# Ruby on rails passing object in named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading rails guides - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
I am not able to understand the syntax: `redirect_to @article` inside the method :

```
def create  
  @article = Article.new(article_params)  
  if @article.save  
    redirect_to @article
  else  
    render 'new'  
  end  
end
```

and also I am not able to comprehend the syntax- `url: article_path(@article)`
inside the defination of form

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Here we are creating a Article using create method. The block is first creating a article using the article_params send from the form and if the newly created Article is saved to database then we are redirected to the article itself else we are redirected to the form showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you create any article in RoR platform then ideal tutorial is [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles) guide, when you use Rails form then don't need to mention method because rails form built in some method like `get` `post` `put/patch` & `destroy` he automatically understood what kind of your request just follow [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles) also [this](http://railstutorial.org/)

```
def create
 @article = Article.new(article_params)

 @article.save
 redirect_to @article
end

private
 def article_params
   params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text) #-> passing article parameters 
end
```